# How to restrict user from accessing static content

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my MVC "E-learning" Project i have one Folder "Course" in that every use have folder in that each user have one file "index.html".

my problem is like no one can directly access that folder page

user1 can not access user2 folder content or not any one can access folder content except who has right.

"I don't want to use form authentication"

like:

this should not happend.

localhost:7689//Course/User1/index.html

only authorised use can access this no one else can access this.

**Scenario**:

user1 login then he can access only that folder "User1"
localhost:7689//Course/User1/index.html

user2 login then he can access only that folder "User2"
localhost:7689//Course/User2/index.html

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just simple:

step 1:

```
In RouteConfig.cs Add
routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;
```

step 2: Map your Static content url with Controller and Action and check for authirization

```
routes.MapRoute(
      name: "staticFileRoute",
      url: "Courses/{subFolder}/{file}",
      defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "HandleStatic" });
```

In Controller : ---

```
public ActionResult HandleStatic()
    {
        return File(Request.RawUrl, "text/html");
     }
```

step 3: In Web.Config Add

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
```

Remember you cannot get break point to RouteConfig file you get in controller only.

Answer (score -1):

You can password protect directories using htpasswd - Manage user files for basic authentication and create user/password for each user, but you will have to share these login details with each user as and when you create them manually